# Is it true that $\forall n \in \Bbb{N} : (\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{i} ) (\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{a_{i}} ) \ge n^2$ , if all $a_{i}$ are positive?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> **If  $\forall i \in \Bbb{N}: a_{i} \in \Bbb{R}^+$ , is it true that $\forall n \in \Bbb{N} : \big(\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}\big) \big(\sum_{i=1}^{n}
>  \frac{1}{a_{i}}\big) \ge n^2$ ?**

I have been able to prove that this holds for $n=1$ , $n=2$, and $n=3$ using the following lemma:

> **Lemma 1:**  Let $a,b \in \Bbb{R}^+$. If $ab =1$ then $a+b \ge 2$

For example, the case for $n=3$ can be proven like this:

Let $a,b,c \in \Bbb{R}^+$. Then we have:

$(a+b+c)\big(\frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b} + \frac{1}{c}\big) = 1 + \frac{a}{b} + \frac{a}{c} + \frac{b}{a} + 1 + \frac{b}{c} + \frac{c}{a} + \frac{c}{b}  + 1 $

$= 3 + \big(\frac{a}{b}  + \frac{b}{a}\big) + \big(\frac{a}{c} + \frac{c}{a}\big) + \big(\frac{b}{c} + \frac{c}{b}\big) $

By lemma 1, $\big(\frac{a}{b}  + \frac{b}{a}\big) \ge 2$,  $ \big(\frac{a}{c} + \frac{c}{a}\big) \ge 2$ and  $\big(\frac{b}{c} + \frac{c}{b}\big) \ge 2$ , therefore:

$3 + \big(\frac{a}{b}  + \frac{b}{a}\big) + \big(\frac{a}{c} + \frac{c}{a}\big) + \big(\frac{b}{c} + \frac{c}{b}\big) \ge 3 + 2 + 2 +2 = 9 = 3^2 \ \blacksquare $

However I'm not sure the generalized version for all natural $n$ is true. I can't come up with a counterexample and when I try to prove it by induction I get stuck.

Here is my attempt:

Let $P(n)::\big(\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}\big) \big(\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{a_{i}}\big) \ge n^2$

**Base case:** $\big(\sum_{i=1}^{1}a_{i}\big) \big(\sum_{i=1}^{1} \frac{1}{a_{i}}\big) = a_{1} \frac{1}{a_{1}} = 1 = 1^2$ , so $P(1)$ is true.

**Inductive hypothesis:**  I assume $P(n)$ is true.

**Inductive step:**

$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}a_{i}\right) \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} \frac{1}{a_{i}}\right) = \left[\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}\right) + a_{n+1}\right] \left[\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{a_{i}}\right) + \frac{1}{a_{n+1}}\right]$$

$$=\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}\right) \left[\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{a_{i}}\right) + \frac{1}{a_{n+1}}\right] + a_{n+1} \left[\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{a_{i}}\right) + \frac{1}{a_{n+1}}\right]$$

$$=\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}\right)\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{a_{i}}\right) +\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}\right) \frac{1}{a_{n+1}} + a_{n+1} \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{a_{i}}\right) +a_{n+1} \frac{1}{a_{n+1}}$$

$$=\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}\right)\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{a_{i}}\right) +\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}\right) \frac{1}{a_{n+1}} + a_{n+1} \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{a_{i}}\right) +1 $$

$$\underbrace{\ge}_{IH} n^2 + \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}\right) \frac{1}{a_{n+1}} + a_{n+1} \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{a_{i}}\right) + 1$$

And here I don't know what to do with the $\big( \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i} \big) \frac{1}{a_{n+1}} + a_{n+1} \big(\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{a_{i}}\big)$ term.

**Is this inequality true? If it is, how can I prove it? If it isn't, can anyone show me a counterexample?**

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1162430, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1506405 – all found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cbig(%5Csum_%7Bi%3D1%7D%5E%7Bn%7Da_%7Bi%7D%5Cbig)%20%5Cbig(%5Csum_%7Bi%3D1%7D%5E%7Bn%7D%20%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Ba_%7Bi%7D%7D%5Cbig)%20%5Cge%20n%5E2%24&p=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just apply 
$$AM\geq GM\geq HM$$
$$\Longrightarrow \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i}{n}\geq \frac{n}{\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{a_i}}$$
Now the result is immediate.

Here equality holds iff all $a_i's$ are equal.

Hope it helps:)

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

The Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality
\begin{eqnarray*}
(x_1^2+ \cdots +x_n^2) (y_1^2+ \cdots +y_n^2) \geq (x_1 y_1+ \cdots +x_n y_n)^2 
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Nice answer. I was thinking of another way: Use Jensen’s inequality on $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i =1}^{n}1/a_i$.

Answer (score 1):

Well you could just use AM-HM, Cauchy-Schwarz, Chebyshev or the rearrangement inequality or the like. However, I suppose the point of this exercise is to prove AM-HM so let's continue with your efforts. To use induction we need to show that $$A = \frac{1}{a_{n+1}} \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i + a_{n+1}\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{a_i} \ge 2n.$$ It's not hard to show that $x+y\ge2\sqrt{xy}$, hence $$A \ge 2\sqrt{(\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i)(\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{a_i})}.$$ So, by induction hypothesis, $A \ge 2n$. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can use AM-GM:
$$\sum_{k=1}^na_k\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{a_k}\geq n\sqrt[n]{\prod_{k=1}^na_k}\cdot \frac{n}{\sqrt[n]{\prod\limits_{k=1}^na_k}}=n^2.$$

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness:

You may also show the inequality by direct calculation using

- $x + \frac{1}{x} \geq 2$ for $x > 0$

\begin{eqnarray*} \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{i} \right) \left(\sum_{j=1}^{n} \frac{1}{a_{j}} \right)
& = & \sum_{i,j =1}^n \frac{a_i}{a_j} \\
& = & \sum_{\stackrel{i,j =1}{\color{blue}{i=j}}}^n \frac{a_i}{a_j} + \sum_{\stackrel{i,j =1}{\color{blue}{i\neq j}}}^n \frac{a_i}{a_j} \\
& = & n + \sum_{\stackrel{i,j =1}{\color{blue}{i< j}}}^n \left(\frac{a_i}{a_j} + \frac{a_j}{a_i} \right)\\
& \color{blue}{\geq} & n + \sum_{\stackrel{i,j =1}{\color{blue}{i< j}}}^n 2\\
& = & n + 2\binom{n}{2} = n^2\\
\end{eqnarray*}